# Strongswan VPN connection on 22.10 Kinetic

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I'm attempting to configure my laptop to connect to my strongswan server.

I've compiled strongswan 6.0Beta 1 and the Network Manager 1.6 plugin with GTK4.  This resolved the "unable to load editor" problem. Now, I'm able to enter the parameters for the connection, but when I do, I get the following error in the log:

```
<warn>  [1668536147.9582] vpn[0x00..00,"IKE2"]: starting: failure to start VPN service: Failed to execute child process “/usr/local/libexec/ipsec/charon-nm” (No such file or directory)
```

This was not built as part of either package, but appears to reside on the git page.  Am I missing some part of the process or do I just need to clone the charon-nm part of the git and install it?

Comment: Apologies.  The laptop is on Kinetic.  The Server is on Jammy.

Comment: Have a look at the network-manager-strongswan Debian package source code (as the corresponding Ubuntu package is based on it), in particular look at the `rules` file, you'll notice it uses the `--with-charon=/usr/lib/ipsec/charon-nm` configure switch https://salsa.debian.org/debian/network-manager-strongswan/-/tree/master/debian